# Finding relative z-ordering of elements programatically in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

In a `grid`, I have added two `FrameworkElements` at the same position in the application. Now, the one I add later is visible to the user. Thus, changing the compile time ordering in `XAML` decides which element would be visible.

However, I want to determine this programatically - i.e. if I mark both of them visible, which element is truly visible to the user? How can I do this?

Example XAML below

```
<Page>
    <Grid x:Name="Greedy">
        <Button x:Name="B1" Content="Button1" Margin="0,440,0,0" Height="100" Width="370"Visibility="Visible"/>
        <Button x:Name="B2" Content="Button1" Margin="0,440,0,0" Height="110" Width="380"Visibility="Visible"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that, when you can simply set the `Canvas.ZIndex` attached property?

Comment: I am building a viewability SDK and my job is to write code to check if any UIElement covers the ad. Hence, I cannot control the creation of UI, but I still need to know, if the ad is covered or not. I have found intersecting elements etc, but cannot determine if intersecting element is behind the ad or on top of it.

Comment: @Clemens - do I make sense in explanation, is there a solution to achieve what I want to  know?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing code that seems to be working. Essentially using `VisualTree` property that elements in its child are ordered in which they appear in the UI

```
private bool iSElement1OnTop(FrameworkElement element1, FrameworkElement element2) {
            IDictionary<int, FrameworkElement> element1Parent = new Dictionary<int, FrameworkElement>();

            FrameworkElement parent = element1;
            int depth = 0;
            while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) != null) {
                FrameworkElement tempParent = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                element1Parent.Add(tempParent.GetHashCode(), parent);
                parent = tempParent;
            }

            parent = element2;
            int hashCode = 0;
            while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) != null) {
                FrameworkElement tempParent = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                if (element1Parent.ContainsKey(tempParent.GetHashCode())) {
                    hashCode = tempParent.GetHashCode();
                    parent = tempParent;
                    break;
                }

                element1Parent.Add(parent.GetHashCode(), parent);
            }

            int indexEl1 = 0;
            int indexEl2 = 0;

            element1 = element1Parent[hashCode];

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++) {
                FrameworkElement e = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

                if (e.GetHashCode() == element1.GetHashCode()) {
                    indexEl1 = i;
                }
                else if (e.GetHashCode() == element2.GetHashCode()) {
                    indexEl2 = i;
                }
            }

            if (indexEl1 > indexEl2) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```